# Прокрутка вниз livewire после загрузки данных

Tags: javascript, laravel, blade, livewire, alpine.js

как как сделать прокрутку вниз после загрузки всех данных в blade?
При нажатии отправляется запрос в бд, и после данные отображаются на экране. Если данных много то появляется прокрутка вниз. Как сделать чтобы сразу прокрутилось вниз?

Пробовал отправлять событие из LW, но оно не срабатывало:

```
 Livewire.on('goBottom', (event) => {
    var block = $('.procrutka-messages');
    block.scrollTop = block.scrollHeight;
 })
```